# how to get filenames only of images from amazon s3 laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I want to get only names of files from server s3 amazon. i am doing like that

```
$files = \Storage::files('app/public/');
```

but this gives me all the files but i dont want to bring images with it but only thier names.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get the name of all files in that folder you can do like this:

```
$filesName = [];

$allFiles = \File::allFiles(public_path());

foreach($allFiles as $file) {

   array_push($filesName, $file->getFilename())

}

print_r($fileNames);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But doesn't it get all the files first and then fetch its names. Because in that folder there are thousand of files.

Comment: Yea thats right it gets the all files first and then their names, i don't know anyway to get the files name before getting those files first, maybe you can do this on a queue job if it  takes so long